# Can you stream videos from Android to Google Drive?

Tags: android, video, google-drive-api, video-streaming, google-drive-android-api

Using Google Drive API for Android, can one stream videos in real time directly to Google Drive storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you cannot stream videos from Android to Google Drive.**